# problems with mysql innodb_lock_wait_timeout attribute on the mysql in the coud

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am currently working on an application built in yii2 and I have an error in my MySQL in the cloud and I have the following error.

> General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting
> transaction

Googling I found that it can be solved by changing this parameter in MySQL `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` but I don't know how to do it in the MySQL in the cloud

some help?

sorry for my English is very very bad

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a database flag as stated on this link https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags

Search for 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout'

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30380492)